# Perl - edit in Windows but run directly on Unix shell?

Tags: windows, perl, shell, shebang

I write my Perl code in Textpad (which I believe is only avai in Windows).  I run it on Linux cmd prompt by calling the Perl interpreter explicitly, e.g. "perl script.pl".  I was wondering if it's possible to run it simply as in "./script.pl".  When I add the shebang in Windows, the Linux prompt complains "command not found", but it works fine if I call it with Perl, and also works fine after I dos2unix the script, so the issue seems to be the shebang not being parsed correctly.  Any suggestions?  Why does the rest of the Windows-formatted code work but not the shebang?

Comment: Perhaps you should say what your shebang looks like? For all we know, your shebang could be `#!C:\Perl\Perl.exe`.

Comment: Have you set the executable permission on the script file? `chmod u+x script.pl`.

Comment: @choroba Unless I am mistaken, if that was the problem the error would be `Permission denied`.

Comment: @TLP: True. Silly me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that Windows prefers a different line ending convention (CRLF, or `\r\n`) than other operating systems (LF, or `\n`). Your editor is creating files with `\r\n` line endings by default.

The shebang is parsed by the operating system, which is not as forgiving as Perl about the stray `\r` at the end of the command. It tries to run `/usr/bin/perl\r`, which doesn't exist.

Your text editor should be able to save the script with Unix line-endings. This won't cause problems with using it on Windows, though a few Windows text editors (including Notepad) won't recognize the line endings properly. This will make it work properly on Linux.

Comment: Awesome - indeed Textpad allows saving files in Unix format.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The first line of your file is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl<CR><LF>
```

`<LF>` is the line terminator, so the OS tries to launch `/usr/bin/perl<CR>`. There is no such program. `dos2unix` changes the first line to

```
#!/usr/bin/perl<LF>
```

`<LF>` is the line terminator, so the OS tries to launch `/usr/bin/perl` and succeeds.